# Using WHERE ... IN in a Postgres Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create a function in Postgres along the lines of this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getAvailableForms (
    get_form_names  TEXT[]
) RETURNS TABLE (
    id          INTEGER,
    name        TEXT,
    location    TEXT,
    created     TIMESTAMP
) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT *
          FROM form
         WHERE form.name IN get_form_names;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER;
```

However, it tells me that `WHERE form.name IN get_form_names` is syntactically incorrect.

I can't find any documentation on how to use array variables in a postgres function call.

Anyway, is it possible to use an array value passed as a function argument in a `WHERE ... IN`?

Comment: I forgot to mention something...  if you are really doing `select *`, then you don't need to declare the table as the output.  Instead you could do `RETURNS SETOF form AS` instead of `RETURNS TABLE ( ... ) AS`.  I realize this may be a primitive example to demonstrate your issue, but if you really are literally returning every field from the "form" table, this might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `any`:

```
where form.name = any (get_form_names)
```

`in` would be for a discrete list of items, but `any` is used for an array.

Comment: "in would be for a discrete list of items, but any is used for an array" - thanks, I've learnt something new today :)

will accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed

Comment: I'm glad.  Read up on postgresql's arrays.  They are a game changer.